# How do I compile a react native project to Android apk file

Tags: react-native, cygwin, visual-studio-2017

I wrote the code for the app in Visual basic. I was also using the cygwin terminal for making files, folders, installing packages etc. Expo also so that I can run the emulator. I now have the folder in Visual basic so how do I convert it to an apk file? Please help.

Comment: If you have created the project with CRNA (create-react-native-app) you need to **eject** it first and then just follow the instructions in the official react-native documentation.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: Thanks. I will try that as soon as possible.